# How to check react native project output in virutual device

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am new in react-native,With the use of command (react-native init projectname ) i successfully create project and installed android studio,Now i want to see my project output in my android mobile instead of emulator,How can i do this ? How can we use avd manager for virtual device ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device), you should:

1. Connect your phone to your device via USB cable ensuring USB debugging is enabled on the phone
2. Run the command `react-native run-android`

If there is only one Android device connected it should deploy to your phone automatically